# Maven Project with multi modules is unable to find pom.xml of modules - Jenkins/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, testng

I created a Maven Project on Jenkins that will clone a mercurial branch from Butbucket, so I can run my Selenium TestNG Scripts. I have tried wiping out the workspace to have a clean build, but it resulted in the same error as before. Also, I checked for each module in my jenkins workspace for the pom.xml files and they are all present. Click the image for the error report from the console. I am not understanding why both Jenkins and Eclipse is unable to find the pom.xml file of my dependencies when it is in the same project folder.

[Image: Jenkins Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2zO0.png)

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>PSWebTestFramework</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.guidewire.pstesting</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>pswtf-test-tp-pc</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.guidewire.pstesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>pswtf-application-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.guidewire.pstesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>pswtf-test-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.guidewire.pstesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>pswtf-test-tp-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.guidewire.pstesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>pswtf-application-tp-pc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.guidewire.pstesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>pswtf-application-ootb-pc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>META-INF/*.SF</excludes>
                <excludes>META-INF/*.DSA</excludes>
                <excludes>META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                <argLine>-Dorg.uncommons.reportng.escape-output=false</argLine>   <!-- get html in reports rather than string -->
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>false</value> <!-- disabling default listeners is optional -->
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter, org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/test/conf</additionalClasspathElement>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/test/testdata</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

UPDATE:
Based on the solution below I altered my job configurations and according to the image below and I was able to get a SUCCESS instead of failure.

[Image: Job Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHiQW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the screenshot that you attached means that the artifact id "pswtf-test-tp-pc" is not able to find the dependency in the local Maven repo.

Build all the projects from parent POM using maven `<modules>` tags. Add this in pom.xml in parent folder with artifact id PSWebTestFramework. Run this parent pom first and then from your project - pswtf-test-tp-pc

```
<modules>
    <module>pswtf-application-core</module>
    <module>pswtf-test-core</module>
    <module>pswtf-test-tp-core</module>
    <module>pswtf-application-tp-pc</module>
</modules>
```

This should build the each module and install it in local maven repo.

P.S. - use `mvn clean install` command to install dependencies in local repo.

Comment: I already have a modules tag in my parent pom.xml file and tried using that command without success. It results in a testng exception, which I believe means it started to do the selenium script, but failed when there was not a testng.xml file to load.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added 'clean install' to the goal in Jenkins and the build was successful.